# How can temperature be constant during a reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, temperature

So I was reading my textbook about the topic thermodynamics.

[image]

Here the second paragraph States that the above equation describes the combustion of liquid ethanol at constant temperature and pressure.

But how can the reaction occur at constant temperature. The enthalpy change stated is accompanying the reaction at standard state. So it should be heat released at constant pressure and from temperature 25°C. So temperature of reaction mixture should be decreased.

Comment: The reaction obviously doesn't happen at a constant temperature. For such a reaction the heat generated is measured in a calorimeter. The calorimeter basically has a large reservoir of water. The amount of water is enough so that the calorimeter only heats up a few degrees. Knowing how much heat it takes to raise the temperature by 1 degree and how many degrees the temperature increased allows the heat of reaction to be calculated.

Comment: Another way of handling this problem is to say that the temperature may change during the reaction, but the only important data is the fact that the initial and the final temperatures must be the same.

Comment: As an addition to @Maurice: this is allowed as long as the intermediate temperature change does not lead to a different outcome (other than wrt.reaction time, which is not regarded in thermodynamics).

Comment: Since enthalpy is a state function, it doesn't matter if the temperature is constant during the reaction.  All that matters is that the final temperature is forced to equal to the initial temperature.  This can be done by holding the reaction mixture in contact with a constant temperature reservoir until the system equilibrates.  You just need to figure out how much heat you had to add (or remove) to make the final temperature the same as the initial temperature.

Answer (score 1):

> But how can the reaction occur at constant temperature

Despite the dynamic name, thermodynamics is not concerned about time. Or more precisely, the theoretical model/world-view of thermodynamics allows the reaction to take place over an infinite amount of time, so you have all the time you need to dissipate the heat and thus keep the same temperature constant (within arbitrarily small limits).

To get to practical reality, we have a whole arsenal of possibilities that cover a range from very close to the definition here to experimental conditions that are quite different from those stated here:

The closest one is: The reaction takes place in a *thermostat*, i.e. in a device that keeps the temperature constant. You may measure the amount of heat that needs to be transported into or out of the reaction vessel to keep the temperature there constant (within practical limits).

As @MaxW says in their comment, you can also approximate this by using a reaction vessel that keeps the temperature approximately constant.

@Maurices comment goes yet a step further: as long as the outcome doesn't change (e.g., no irreversible reations at the intermediate temperature), you may deliberately allow intermediate temperature changes as long as you can keep track of the heat exchange until the reaction products reach the starting temperature again.

And lastly, you could allow temperature change and do a series of experiments that then allows you separate in the data analysis temperature-dependent from temperature-independent parts.